# Why From<T> for U implies Into<U> for T in Rust?

Tags: rust

This is how I'd implement the `Into` trait to convert an `i32` to the set of squared numbers:

```
impl Into<SquaredNumber> for i32 {
    fn into(number: i32) -> SquaredNumber {
        SquaredNumber(i32::pow(2, number))
    }
}
```

According to https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html:

```
From<T> for U implies Into<U> for T
```

how is it possible that `From<SquaredNumber>` is now implemented just because I implemented `Into`? Given a `SquaredNumber(16)`, it's not obvious that it turns into `4: i32`, it could be `-4: i32`.

How does this work?

Comment: you get it wrong, you should implement from that will auto implement into not the other way around. Thank to blanked implementation https://doc.rust-lang.org/std/convert/trait.Into.html#implementors

Comment: `impl From<i32> for SquaredNumber` would imply `impl Into<SquaredNumber> for i32`, there is no `SquaredNumber` -> `i32` being generated.